# Why doesn't $(document).width() work in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

Trying  to get this to work:

```
width = $(document).width();
  if (width > 600) {
    $('#anim').animate({
      width: '100vw',
  }, 500, "linear");
} else  {
  $('#anim').remove();
}
```

It seems  the animation runs regardless of width size?

P.S. Don't want to use  $(window).width()

Any ideas??

Comment: What's the problem occurring?

Comment: Hi, like in the if statement the animation  plays when width of document is larger than 600px and also when is  smaller  than 600px. I  want the animation not to play if document is less than 600px. It works  if I use $(window).width() but I thought there might be another way...

Answer (score 0):

`$(document).width()` works fine (Chrome, FF, Edge).

Do you have insert the block inside a ready block? Maybe the document is not ready, at the moment, the code is executed…

```
$(function() {
  width = $(document).width();
  if (width > 600) {
    $('#anim').animate({
      width: '100vw',
    }, 500, "linear");
  } else  {
    $('#anim').remove();
  }
});
```

Comment: Still doesn't  work like it should, even inside a ready block...

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!

The solution was to set the (document) to (document.documentElement)